# P-value column in table1 - using table1 function

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

NOTE - im referring to `table1` function, not `tableOne`

As you might know `table1` package summarizes the data into table by putting up some variable against all the others (like how many males vs females - smoked, got the drug, etc..)

Very good guidelines about the `table1` function here.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

In lowest part of link site above you can see the writer making p-value column by using trick since the command is not built into `table1`. The thing is that its no problem with his code since he is only dealing with "male" and "female" (2 variables).. and im trying to do it with 4 variables.

Im fitting it so it can use my variables, im getting error and need help

ERROR

> "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NACalling var(x) on a
> factor x is deprecated and will become an error.   Use something like
> 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.Error in if
> (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data
> are essentially constant") :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

```
a <- c(0,13.3,14.0,14.7,15.8,999.0)

dat1$RDWquintiles<-cut(dat1$RDW_pre,a,include.lowest = TRUE)

z <- levels(dat1$RDWquintiles)
dat1$RDWquintiles <- factor(dat1$RDWquintiles,levels=c(z,factor("P-value")),labels=c("0,13.3","13.3,14","14,14.7","14.7,15.8","15.8,999","P-values" ))

dat1$RDWquintiles

table(dat1$RDWquintiles)


rndr <- function(x, name, ...) {
    if (length(x) == 0) {
        y <- dat1[[name]]
        s <- rep("", length(render.default(x=y, name=name, ...)))
        if (is.numeric(y)) {
            p <- t.test(y, dat1$RDWquintiles)$p.value
        } else {
            p <- chisq.test(table(y, droplevels(dat1$RDWquintiles)))$p.value
        }
        s[2] <- sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001))
        s
    } else {
        render.default(x=x, name=name, ... ,)
    }
}

rndr.strat <- function(label, n, ...) {
    ifelse(n==0, label, render.strat.default(label, n, ...))
}

table1(~ Age + Sex + LOS + Open + adm_PE |RDWquintiles,data=dat1, droplevels=F, render=rndr, render.strat=rndr.strat, overall=F)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to check your data. I don't have your dataset so I can't reproduce your error. The only issue I see with having 4 groups to compare instead of 2 is that you cannot use a T-test for continuous variables, you would need to choose an appropriate test like ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis to derive the P-value (in general, the P-value depends on the test used; selecting an appropriate test is an important consideration, but outside the scope of the current question).

Here I have adapted the example from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html) (I don't repeat the whole code, just the relevant changes):

```
lalonde$age.quartiles <- eqcut(lalonde$age, 4, varlabel="Age")
lalonde$age.quartiles <- factor(lalonde$age.quartiles,
    levels=c(levels(lalonde$age.quartiles), "P-value"))

rndr <- function(x, name, ...) {
    if (length(x) == 0) {
        y <- lalonde[[name]]
        s <- rep("", length(render.default(x=y, name=name, ...)))
        if (is.numeric(y)) {
            p <- kruskal.test(y ~ lalonde$age.quartiles)$p.value
        } else {
            p <- chisq.test(table(y, droplevels(lalonde$age.quartiles)))$p.value
        }
        s[2] <- sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001))
        s
    } else {
        render.default(x=x, name=name, ...)
    }
}

table1(~ black + hispan + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78 | age.quartiles,
    data=lalonde, droplevels=F, render=rndr, render.strat=rndr.strat, overall=F)
```

Note: this is not part of the original question, but I thought I would mention that the `table1` package contains the function `eqcut` which can be conveniently used to create equal-sized groups such as tertiles, quartiles, etc.

Comment: Any way to use `overall = T` and p-value column at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can. See https://github.com/benjaminrich/table1/issues/72.